# Entity Framework passing array of integers to endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am passing an array of integers to an API endpoint composed in a model such as:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public IList<int> ints { get; set; }
}
```

My endpoint to hit is:

```
Get["/myobjects/{id:int}"] = _ =>
{
    var ints = this.Bind<SomeModel>();
    return myService.someMethod1((int)_.id, ints.Ints));
};
```

Then, when I want to query the object in the DB,

```
 var count = context.ReadOnly<SomeModel>()
                .Query(x => x.myId == id && // id is already defined
                    ints != null &&
                    ints.Contains(x.SomeModelId))
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .Count();
```

I am using Entity Framework as an ORM.

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]]'.

Or I get:

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
>
> Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

The exception states that it can't create a null constant value, but I am populating the array that is coming in - so I don't understand why it is throwing this error.

EDIT: The array of ints is not being bound and the list is null. Does anybody know how to correctly bind to the list?

Comment: This isn't an EntityFramework issue now that you have found out that your `ints` object isn't being bound correctly. You should also tag with MVC Next (or whatever the MVC 6 tag is) as the binding is different in the new version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have in mind all that checks you are doing in the lamdba are **inside the query** this means EF most probably will try to evaluate them to SQL.

But what you are checking is a variable that is not a part of the query. When the case is this, you need to split the check for null outside the query.

```
var query = context.ReadOnly<SomeModel>().Query(x => x.myId == id);
if (ints != null) {
    query = query.Where(x => ints.Contains(x.SomeModelId);
}
var count = query.Select(x => x.Id).Count();
```

If I understood well the business case, if `ints` is null, the whole query will evaluate to `false`, so you most probably will be satisfied to just checking if `ints` is null -> if true, the count is zero. Otherwise - query the database.

```
var count = 0;
if (ints != null)
{
    count = context.ReadOnly<SomeModel>()
                .Query(x => x.myId == id &&
                    ints.Contains(x.SomeModelId))
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .Count();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me find one bug, which is that the list is essentially null. I edited the description.